# Promotions above 7?

Tags: civilization-6

I have had a unit and been steadily upgrading it.

It now has 7 promotions - and is due another - however when I click the icon on the side of the screen there is no way to do the promotion.

I guess this is a bug? (I am on Mac where the first patch is not yet available).

Comment: What ability would you expect the unit to have?

Comment: No idea - maybe +5 attack strength.

Comment: After 7th promotion they are old and need retirement :)). If you click them they'll start saying things like "during my days we were using polished iron to redirect sun light so we can see inside the cave".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Units which are eligible for promotion, but have no valid promotions, run into this UI issue where you are prompted to promote them despite being unable to do so.

You can run into this with Apostles too -- once they're out of upgrades (you can pick each twice), every Apostle trained will generate an alert because it's "promotion eligible" despite being unable to pick a talent.

Comment: So I guess this goes into the bug column then? Is there any mandated behaviour? At the very least you should be able to promote to heal.